# Append dynamically generated barcode image to previously generated image

Tags: jquery, append, barcode, dynamically-generated

I am generating the barcode image for the selected rows, but at the end, only the last image is getting displayed, anyone can help me to append the previously generated image to currently generated image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode/jquery-barcode.js "></script>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
function generateBarcode() {   
var settings = {
output:'css',
bgColor: '#FFFFFF',
color: '#000000',
barWidth: '1',
barHeight: '50',
moduleSize: '5',
posX: '10',
posY: '20',
addQuietZone: '1'
};  
var tbl = document.getElementById("myDynamicTableBody");
if (tbl != null) {          
for (var i = 0; i <= tbl.rows.length-1; i++) {
var checkid = 'ck'+i;                   
var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkid);                    
if(checkbox.checked){                                                               
var val = tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;           
alert(tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
alert(val);                 
//show the barcode for each selected row
$("#overlay").barcode(val, "code11", settings);                                     
}                   
}
}
}
</script> 
<body>
<hr/>
<div id="overlay"> </div>
<hr/>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="myDynamicTable">
<thead>
<tr><th>Reward ID</th>
<th>Issue Date</th>
<th>Expiration Date</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Select</th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myDynamicTableBody">
<tr>
<td>1234567891</td>
<td>9/22/2013</td>
<td>12/05/2015</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="tcbox" id="ck0" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1234567892</td>
<td>9/22/2013</td>
<td>12/05/2015</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="tcbox" id="ck1" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1234567893</td>
<td>9/22/2013</td>
<td>12/05/2015</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="tcbox" id="ck2" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1234567894</td>
<td>9/22/2013</td>
<td>12/05/2015</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="tcbox" id="ck3" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1234567895</td>
<td>9/22/2013</td>
<td>12/05/2015</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="tcbox" id="ck4" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="print selected" onclick="generateBarcode()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a `var $img` variable in which you store the currently generated image and then when the next image is generated , append `$img` to this newly image

Comment: it is not working
var $img = $("#overlay").barcode(val, "code11", settings).append($('img'));

Comment: is this `$("#overlay").barcode(val, "code11", settings)` gives you the image ?

Comment: yes try loading the code.

Comment: please help me to display the barcode image one by one as list.